# Issue with client tls authentication

Tags: go

I have issue with client authentication via certificate in GoLang. From trace I see that server is requesting certificate but certificate is not send in client response.

[image]

Here is my Go code:

package main

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    xml := `
    <Packet>
<Header>
 <ID>1231232132132354234</ID>
 </Header>
 <Body>
 <Item>
 <Content>SMS</Content>
 <Phone_no>+123123213</Phone_no>
 <Content>test</Content>
 <OriginAddress>Posiljatelj</OriginAddress>
 </Item>
 </Body>
</Packet>
    `

    // Load client cert
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("../cert/certNEW.pem", "../cert/serverNEW.key")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Load CA cert
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../cert/cacerts.cer")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    // Setup HTTPS client
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
        RootCAs:            caCertPool,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()
    transport := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig}
    client := &http.Client{Transport: transport}

    resp, err := client.Post("https://api.url", "text/xml", bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(xml)))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(contents))
}
```

I got pfx certificate from client, what i did is that I extraceted public client certificate, private certificate and rootRA public part and I assrted in Go code.

Comment: What does your go code report when run?

Comment: Are you sure that serverNEW.key is also the key for the client certificate? That seems odd. Servers would usually never disclose their key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable `InsecureSkipVerify` by setting `InsecureSkipVerify: false,`

It causes the chain arguments to be nil https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/

> ```
>   // If normal verification is disabled by
>     // setting InsecureSkipVerify, or (for a server) when ClientAuth is
>     // RequestClientCert or RequireAnyClientCert, then this callback will
>     // be considered but the verifiedChains argument will always be nil.
> ```

Comment: I set `InsecureSkipVerify: fals` but it is stil the same. The client does not send certificate in response to request which requests client certificate for auth.
`tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
  Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert},
  RootCAs:            caCertPool,
  InsecureSkipVerify: false,
 }
`